# Local time with dual-boot

Tags: 11.10, dual-boot, time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does time change in Ubuntu after installing Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90504/why-does-time-change-in-ubuntu-after-installing-windows)

I have a dual-boot pc (ubuntu/Windows 7). When I boot with Ubuntu my local time (Rome fuse) is correct. But when i boot with wimdows my time is one hour slow. How can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this by either asking windows to set the hardware clock with UTC, or Ubuntu to use localtime.

To make the change in Ubuntu, edit edit /etc/default/rcS and change

`UTC=yes` to no, like this:

```
# assume that the BIOS clock is set to UTC time (recommended)
UTC=no
```

See:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime#Multiple_Boot_Systems_Time_Conflicts