# Problem with Time & Date

Tags: dual-boot, hard-drive

I have two hard disks in my PC (160 GB & 80 GB). The 160 GB hard disk has Ubuntu 12.04 installed in it while the 80 GB hard disk has Windows XP. I added the 80 GB hard disk just a few days ago, before which I was using only the hard disk with Ubuntu.

Before the addition of the second hard disk, the Time & Date settings worked fine in Ubuntu(It showed the correct time and date every time I booted my PC). But now, whenever I boot my system, the time is wrong. Even if I set it correctly it becomes wrong the next time I boot my PC.

What is causing this problem and how can I resolve it?

Comment: Ubuntu uses UTC by default. Windows uses local time.  You can make ubuntu use local time as described here: [Why does time change in Ubuntu after installing Windows](http://askubuntu.com/q/90504/107450)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the way the two operating systems set the hardware clock. Ubuntu uses UTC, and Windows localtime. to fix this error, please visit:

[Why does time change in Ubuntu after installing Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/90504/why-does-time-change-in-ubuntu-after-installing-windows?rq=1)

and go to the first answer.