# Windows time resets even when doing the fix

Tags: windows-7, time

I am dualbooting ubuntu 13.10 and windows 7.
When I boot into ubuntu and then into windows, the windows time is +2 hours of the correct time.

I know this has to do with the way the operating systems handle BIOS time. For ubuntu it is UTC and for windows is local time.

So I searched about it and found that i need to make a .reg file with these contents and then run it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation]
     "RealTimeIsUniversal"=dword:00000001
```

But it doesn't work. Even if I do it, after some time windows changes the clock again to +2 hours... I also tried rebooting immediately after doing the fix, but still nothing.

Comment: That only works with Windows 7 and Service Pack 2. Still... this is a windows problem that Ubuntu made a wiki page for to fix it... This is how to fix this from Ubuntu:http://askubuntu.com/questions/90504/why-does-time-change-in-ubuntu-after-installing-windows?rq=1

Comment: I have windows 7 service pack 1. What do you mean service pack 2? Here http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/service-packs-download#sptabs=win7 it says that SP 1 is the latest.