# How to set up GRUB after 14.04 and Windows 8.1 are installed?

Tags: 14.04, grub2, windows-8

I have installed Ubuntu x64 bit on my Toshiba Satellite laptop. If I turn off the UEFI boot and change to CSM boot, Ubuntu will load. If not, Windows loads like normal which is fine.

My other problem is that I cannot get the option to choose which operating system I want to load. This is what is bothering me the most. I have ran the command prompt as an admin and ran the

```
bcdedit /set "{bootmgr}" path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

command. Anyone have any suggestions? I'd greatly appreciate it.

---

PS

I use Malwarebytes and Windows Defender as anti-virus on Windows.  Is there anything I should use for Ubuntu?

Also

When I switch from UEFI to CSM, my clock time moves 5 hours forward. Please comment below for these issues.

Comment: Sounds like you installed in CSM, so you installed grub-pc (to MBR and the grub-bios flagged partition).  In that case, you have no bootloader at all in /EFI/ubuntu, do you?  You need to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode to dual boot Windows in a normal way.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/90504/why-does-time-change-in-ubuntu-after-installing-windows for the time change problem.

Comment: I did configure my Toshiba Satellite Laptop to dual boot alongside windows 8.1 I did encounter similar issues. The steps and references can be found at the following link. http://askubuntu.com/questions/399110/dual-boot-issues-with-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-04/402927#402927